# Swing: non input text field

Tags: java, swing

I'm new in Swing, and don't want to learn it. I just want to write a simple frame divided into two equal parts: top and bottom. The top part of frame should be a simple immutable text field.

***Problem:*** As I understand, to show text with beautiful font I should use JTextPane. But JTextPane:

1. Doesn't support vertical text alignment; (I haven't got any desire to write something like [that](http://java-sl.com/tip_center_vertically.html))
2. I don't know how to switch off editing.

***Quedtion*** I believe there is a simpler solution for my purpose. Is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The top part of frame should be a simple immutable text field.

Use a JLabel. It supports HTML which might help with your formatting.

> I don't know how to switch off editing.

```
setEditable( false );
```